# jQuery tokeninput change selected item to another div not parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
 <div class="update_genre_list">
        <input type="text" class="custom_input" id="suggestion_sub_genre" placeholder="">            
      </div>

  $.ajax({
          url: "<%= genre_suggestion_search_artists_path %>",
          data: {select_genre:select_genre},
          type: 'get',
          success: function(data) {
              $(".update_genre_list").parent().find('ul').remove();
              $("#suggestion_sub_genre").tokenInput(data,{
                  onAdd: function (item) {
                     $(".token_save").append('<li class="token-input-token"><p>'+item.name+'</p><span class="token-input-delete-token remove_token">×</span></li>');


                  }
              });
          }
      });
```

I want to show tokeninput selected item to another div.Below is the div i want to show.

```
 <div class="token_save"></div>
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably simpler to set up a second tokenInput field and add clones of original tokens to it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="update_genre_list">
    <input type="text" class="custom_input" id="suggestion_sub_genre" placeholder="">
</div>
<div id="token_save">
    <input>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var $token_save_input = $("#token_save input").tokenInput();

$.ajax({
    url: "<%= genre_suggestion_search_artists_path %>",
    data: { select_genre: select_genre },
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data) {
        $(".update_genre_list").parent().find('ul').remove();
        $("#suggestion_sub_genre").tokenInput(data, {
            onAdd: function (item) {
                $token_save_input.tokenInput( 'add', $.extend({}, item) );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

*untested*

I'm not sure that `$.extend(...)` is necessary but it's more guaranteed to ensure independence of the clone from the original than `.tokenInput( 'add', item )`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
How can i add new item if it is not listed ?

Comment: I'm not sure I can answer that because I'm not 100% sure of your goal.